# Can I force my android test to read resources from a specific qualifier?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-resources, android-resource-qualifiers

I have an android test, when I run in a small device context

but I want to read a resource of large screen context

(under `sw-600` qualifier)

Is there any annotation or code to force that?